# Convert string to become variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have multiple variables containing JSON as string (received from AJAX).

data.output_data_1234

data.output_data_5678

I convert them to Array:

```
var outputdataarr = new Array(data.output_data_1234);
```

This works fine, but how do I add a number to the var name:

```
var outputdataarr = new Array('data.output_data_'+formid+'');
```

this one does not work.

formid contains a proper number.

This does not work too:

```
var outputvar = window['data.output_data_' + formid];
var outputdataarr = new Array(outputvar);
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean, you need something like this:

```
var outputdataarr = new Array(data['output_data_'+formid]);
```

You can only use string in square brackets as an object field identifier. It cannot contain '.'.

UPDATE:
However, you will probably need a loop to fill the whole array, e.g.

```
var outputdataarr = new Array();    
for (var i=1000; i<2000; i++) {
  outputdataarr.push(data['output_data_'+formid]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` instead of `new Array` is better.

```
var outputdataarr = [];
outputdataarr.push(data['output_data_'+formid]);
//and so on
```